# When connected to a secure WiFi network, is your traffic safe from others on the same network?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, sniffing

If two users are on the same secure WiFi network, is there a way to sniff the traffic like you might on an unsecure network?

Answer (score 3):

yes, unless you're using wpa enterprise. Anyone knowing password or connected to this network by switch, etc. is able to perform for example man in the middle attack to sniff your passwords. Something like client isolation on wireless ap may help to prevent this.

Comment: Sounds about right to me.  If they have a key to your house, then game over. The solution is to have separate keys to each bedroom.